# Iterator operand 0 dtype could not be cast from dtype('<M8[us]') to dtype('<M8[D]') according to the rule 'safe'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to form a Black-Scholes Model by writing codes, but the error happened.

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

def time_to_maturity(t0, T, y=252):
    t0 = pd.to_datetime(t0)
    T = pd.to_datetime(T)
    return ( np.busday_count(t0, T) / y )

time_to_maturity('2018-08-01', '2018-12-14')


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-c71b621d9d71> in <module>
     10     return ( np.busday_count(t0, T) / y )
     11 
---> 12 time_to_maturity('2018-08-01', '2018-12-14')

<ipython-input-20-c71b621d9d71> in time_to_maturity(t0, T, y)
      8     t0 = pd.to_datetime(t0)
      9     T = pd.to_datetime(T)
---> 10     return ( np.busday_count(t0, T) / y )
     11 
     12 time_to_maturity('2018-08-01', '2018-12-14')

<__array_function__ internals> in busday_count(*args, **kwargs)

**TypeError: Iterator operand 0 dtype could not be cast from dtype('<M8[us]') to dtype('<M8[D]') according to the rule 'safe'**
```

I can't understand what the problem is. How can I fix this one?

Comment: I think the problem is related with the format 'datetime'...

Answer (score 1):

Checking, I found that the argument of `np.busday_count()` needs to be in datetime64 format. So I used `np.datetime64()` to convert it.

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

def time_to_maturity(t0, T, y=252):
    t0 = np.datetime64(t0)
    T = np.datetime64(T)
    return ( np.busday_count(t0, T) / y )

time_to_maturity('2018-08-01', '2018-12-14')
0.38492063492063494
```

Comment: is this because of the difference of np and pd's datetime format?

Comment: In pandas it was in the timestamp format, so I checked and found that the 'datetime64' format was needed. From [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.busday_count.html)